# Testcafe request mock response resolves if filter is a string, is set on pending if using Regex, Object or Predicate

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am posting this here since this seems not be a bug with Testcafe, but some sort of weird behaviour with the RequestMock https://testcafe.io/documentation/402763/reference/test-api/requestmock/onrequestto#select-requests-to-be-handled-by-the-hook

My scenario is the following: I am mocking several calls to a Rails API used by a React App when running E2E tests via Testcafe on my React APP.

When mocking the request to my API I do not understand why if I pass a string to `onRequestTo` e.g.

```
export const createProtocolSuccess = RequestMock()
  .onRequestTo('http://localhost:3000/api/protocols')
  .respond((req, res) => {
    res.headers['access-control-allow-origin'] = '*';
    res.headers['access-control-allow-headers'] =
      'expiry,uid,client,access-token,token-type,content-type';
    res.headers['access-control-allow-credentials'] = 'false';
    res.setBody(req.body);
    res.statusCode = 200;
  });
```

The request is mocked and the response resolves immediately, the status is a `200` so I can use a `RequestLogger` in my tests

```
import { RequestLogger } from 'testcafe';

export const submitProtocolLogger = RequestLogger(
  { url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/protocols', method: 'POST' },
  {
    logRequestBody: true,
    stringifyRequestBody: true,
    logResponseHeaders: true,
    logResponseBody: true
  }
);
```

to check the data sent to the endpoint e.g.

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';
import modalMetadata from '../page-objects/modal-metadata';
import { nextFriday } from '../../../helpers/nextFriday';
import { validateTokenMockSuccess } from '../mocks/validateTokenMock';
import { fetchCategories } from '../mocks/categoriesMock';
import { submitProtocolLogger } from '../mocks/submitProtocolLogger';
import { createProtocolSuccess } from '../mocks/protocolsMock';

fixture('Create protocol')
  .page('http://localhost:4200/admin/protocols')
  .requestHooks([
    validateTokenMockSuccess,
    fetchCategories,
    createProtocolSuccess,
    submitProtocolLogger
  ]);

test('Protocol modal metadata', async (t) => {
  await t.click(Selector('.btn-primary'));
  await t
    .expect(Selector('.modal-header').withText('Create a New Protocol').exists)
    .ok('Correctly sets modal header title');
  await modalMetadata.hasLabelFor('title', 'Title');
  await modalMetadata.hasLabelFor('publication-date', 'Publication Date');
  await modalMetadata.hasLabelFor('categories', 'Categories (Select at least two)');
  await modalMetadata.hasButtonFor('Cancel');
  await modalMetadata.typeTitle('New Protocol Title');
  await modalMetadata.selectCategories('Category1');
  await modalMetadata.selectCategories('Category3');
  await modalMetadata.submitForm();
  // await t.debug();
  await t
    .expect(submitProtocolLogger.contains((r) => r.response.statusCode === 200))
    .ok('Request status code is 200')
    .expect(submitProtocolLogger.count(() => true))
    .eql(1, 'Request is called 1 time')
    .expect(submitProtocolLogger.requests[0].request.method)
    .eql('post', 'Request method is of type POST')
    .expect(
      submitProtocolLogger.contains((record) => {
        const requestBody = JSON.parse(record.request.body);
        return (
          requestBody.data.attributes.title === 'New Protocol Title' &&
          requestBody.data.attributes.public === 'false' &&
          requestBody.data.attributes.published_at === nextFriday() &&
          requestBody.data.relationships.categories.data.length === 2
        );
      })
    )
    .ok('Correctly sets new protocol attributes');
  // await submitProtocolLogger.requests;

  submitProtocolLogger.clear();
});
```

If I instead use an object and pass this to `onRequestTo` in the `RequestMock` e.g.

```
export const createProtocolSuccess = RequestMock()
  .onRequestTo({ url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/protocols', method: 'POST' })
  .respond((req, res) => {
    res.headers['access-control-allow-origin'] = '*';
    res.headers['access-control-allow-headers'] =
      'expiry,uid,client,access-token,token-type,content-type';
    res.headers['access-control-allow-credentials'] = 'false';
    res.setBody(req.body);
    res.statusCode = 200;
  });
```

The test fails since by setting a debugger in my test and inspecting the network tab in chrome I see that the request is fired, but the status is set on PENDING???
I tried filtering with a predicate as suggested on here as well

https://testcafe.io/documentation/402763/reference/test-api/requestmock/onrequestto#filter-with-a-predicate

and I also tried with a regex, even returned and resolved a `Promise` into `respond((req, res)` but no matter what, whatever I try the request is fired, the mock gets hit, but the response is always on `PENDING`. Ideally I can live with it and just use strings, but the fact is that I would like to differentiate between requests that could use the same url, like when I am editing a resource; basically the url would be the same e.g.

`'http://localhost:3000/api/protocols'`

but the methods would be `POST` for the `CREATE` and `PATCH` for the `EDIT` actions.

To make a long story short it is not clear to me why the `RequestMock` response only resolves with strings and instead is set always on pending while using an Object, a Regexp or a Predicate as a filter

Any support on this would be highly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the request mocked by `RequestMock` using [various ways](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402763/reference/test-api/requestmock/onrequestto#select-requests-to-be-handled-by-the-hook).
If it works for the string `url` and doesn't work for the object `url`, then it means the object `url` rule doesn't satisfy the target HTTP request.
Note, that

```js
.onRequestTo({ url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/protocols' })
```

and

```js
.onRequestTo('http://localhost:3000/api/protocols')
```

are equavivalent.

To find the cause the issue, I need an example to run it locally. Without it, it's difficult to say something for sure.